# SQL Server limits when deployed on a VM in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

What are the SQL Server limits when deployed on a VM in Azure? Is it the same as 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Azure Databases size is limited to 150GB.

And this General guidelines and limitations of SQL Azure Databases - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx

SQL Server Feature Limitation in SQL Azure - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx

Even though bit old, you can check this - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.comparison-of-sql-server-with-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 16 x 1TB for storage anyway.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn197896.aspx